# How can I update multiple merged cells with Google Sheets API in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to update (With blank info) with batch multiple merged cells with Python using Google Sheets API v4 (No gspread). I have this code:

```
blank = setValue("") <----- I set a variable with no data to delete all the info that the cell can contains
dataBlank = [
        ...
        {
            'range': 'AB83',
            'values': blank
        }
        {
            'range': 'BH75:BH82', # <------- I think here is the problem
            'values': blank
        } ...
    ]

body = {
        'valueInputOption': value_input_option,
        'data': dataBlank
    }
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=registro_id, body=body).execute()
print('{0} celdas borradas - Registro'.format(result.get('totalUpdatedCells')))

def setValue(value):
    rvalue = [value]
    avalue = [rvalue]
    return avalue
```

It runs, but in the sheet it only updates the first cell of the range, and the whole range does'n update.
I try with `'range' : 'BH75:BH82'`, `'range' : 'Sheet1!BH75:BH82'` and I can't update the whole range. I need to use the batch update because I need to check the performance and don't pass the quote limit from Google Cloud.

I het this:

[image: I get this]

Only the first cell is updated. If I update individual cells o merged cells without range it works fine, but if I use a range to update doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put `zero` to the cells `BH75:BH82` in the 1st tab of Google Spreadsheet using the method of Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate in Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In the case of the method of Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate in Sheets API, when you want to put the value to the cells `BH75:BH82`, it is required to be `"values":[["sample"],["sample"],["sample"],["sample"],["sample"],["sample"],["sample"],["sample"]]`.
- In your script, `"values":[["sample"]]` is used. By this, the value is put to only the 1st cell. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
'range': 'BH75:BH82',
'values': zero
```

To:

```
'range': 'BH75:BH82',
'values': [[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value]]
```

- Unfortunately, from your script, I cannot understand about `zero`. So I used `value` as a variable. If you want to put the empty, please declare `value` as `""`.
- This is a simple modification. So, of course, you can also create `[[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value],[value]]` using a script.

#### Note:

- If you want to put a value to a lot of cells, the RepeatCellRequest of batchUpdate method in Sheets API might be useful. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you for your help, another way to erase the data from the sheets is using the method `batchClear()` as follow:
`dataBlank = [
        'BL83', 'AP75:AP82', 'BH75:BH82', 'CF75:CF82', 'AB85:CF91', 'AP85:AP91', 'BH85:BH91', 'CF85:CF91', 'AB95',
        'AT95', 'BL95', 'AC97', 'AT97', 'BI97', 'CA97', 'D100:BN115', 'B117:BG117'
    ]
body = {
        'ranges': dataBlank
    }
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchClear(spreadsheetId=registro_id, body=body).execute()`

Comment: @alexchvrches Thank you for replying and adding the information.